# pass iterated object as an input to html inline defined onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

i have an array which i am iterating through with map() function. in each iteration i am creating a div and i am assigning onclick() to it. how can i pass iterated object as an input to the defined goToMembri() function?

below code is what i managed to implement and it works. i would like to know is there any other way that i can achieve the same result.

```
let mainDiv = document.getElementById('Details');
let nameQuery = @json($username);
nameQuery.map(function(item){
  let row = document.createElement('div');
  row.setAttribute('class', 'rows')
  let username = document.createElement('h3');
  username.setAttribute('class','people')
  username.innerHTML = "Nome: " + item;
  row.appendChild(username);
  return(
    mainDiv.appendChild(row)
  );
});
badgeIdQuery = @json($user_badge_id);
badgeIdQuery.map(function(item){
  let row = document.getElementsByClassName('rows')[0];
  row.setAttribute('id', item)
  row.setAttribute('onclick', "return goToMembri(\'' + id + '\')")
  let badgeId = document.createElement('h3');
  badgeId.innerHTML = "Badge ID: " + item;
  row.appendChild(badgeId);
  return(
    mainDiv.appendChild(row)
  );
});


function goToMembri(item){
  window.location.protocol = "https:";
  window.location.href = "/membri?badge_id="+item;
}
```

badgeIdQuery is just a simple array consists of strings. like: ["100","200"]

Comment: Why not create proper link elements to begin with? “Linking” elsewhere via an onclick handler always seems quite ugly to me, it creates bad UX (can’t easily open such links in new tabs for example.)

Comment: You code makes no sense. You're always trying to get the [0]th row in a for loop. Please post a HTML example as well.

Comment: Also, please post a sample of `badgeIdQuery`.

Comment: You are always doing the same things on a one div !! by ` document.getElementsByClassName('rows')[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- New elements are created by using `document.createElement`, not `getElementByClassName`
- You're always targeting the same row `[0]` inside that loop. That's absolutely wrong.
- Never just target a `.row` anyways. One day you'll have to add more `.row` to your document and you'll wonder why the website is broken.
- There's no point to use `.map()` as an iterator. That's the job for `.forEach()`
- Don't use setAttribute and IDs. You don't need any IDs at all.

Example:

```js
const NewEL = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
const EL_mainDiv = document.querySelector("#mainDiv");

const badgeIdQuery = [2, 5, 9, 17];

badgeIdQuery.forEach((id) => {
  const EL_row = NewEL("div", {
    className: "row",
    innerHTML: `<h3>Badge ID: ${id}</h3>`,
    onclick() {
      const url = "/membri?badge_id="+ id;
      alert(`Navigating to: ${url}`);
      window.location = url;
    }
  });
  EL_mainDiv.append(EL_row);
});
```

```css
.row {
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but it doesn't answer my question. i would like to know how can item be passed to goToMembri as the input parameter